# Raspberry pi libraries for fortran

Tags: raspberry-pi, robotics-library

I'm quite a fan of fortran and I was wondering if there were any libraries to control the GPIO pins in a raspberry pi with it. I find python to be quite slow so I think it is the best option for making it fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is in fact a very simple library called [fortran-gpio](https://github.com/playmoo/fortran-gpio) for exactly that.

Another option is to access GPIO pins through device files, see [here](https://smist08.wordpress.com/2017/12/02/fortran-lives/) for details.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for!